# Gazebo 1.8.0 , typo?

Tags: gazebo

[image: Gazebo Answers logo]

Hi,

I just installed Gazebo from source, and I get the version number 1.8.0, but the [change-log](http://gazebosim.org/wiki/Change_log) doesn't say anything about it. Is it a typo?

Cheers,
Andrei

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.gazebosim.org/question/2487/gazebo-1.8.0-,-typo?/) by [AndreiHaidu](https://answers.gazebosim.org/users/87/andreihaidu/) on Gazebo Answers with karma: 2108 on 2013-04-20

Post score: 0

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Gazebo Answers logo]

I'm assuming you installed from default? It's correct in the latest release branches (1.7 and 1.7.1) ... default often gets pushed to the next minor version to make it easier to separate it from already released versions I think.

---

Originally posted by [ThomasK](https://answers.gazebosim.org/users/16/thomask/) with karma: 508 on 2013-04-20

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 2